# How to change the version of the pre-install software of AppVeyor?

Tags: appveyor

Here's [a link](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-environment/#pre-installed-software).

And such as node.js, the default version is "Node.js 4.0.0 - 4.8.4 (x86 and x64) - default on build workers", how can I make it to the latest stable version?

Answer (score 0):

ok it's my bad. I have solved this problem.
The answer is [testing with Node.js](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/lang/nodejs-iojs/)